# Unexpected '<' when doing REST requests?

Tags: java, rest, jpa, jpql

I have recently been diving into Java Rest. However, everytime I try and do something via Postman, and make a GET request, the result is the same.

[image: [image]]

My REST is written like this:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package rest;

import DBMapper.DBMapper;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import entity.Country;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author William Pfaffe
 */
@Path("world")
public class WorldResource {
    private EntityManager em;
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private DBMapper db = new DBMapper(em, emf);
    private List<Country> list;
    private final  Gson gson = new com.google.gson.GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of WorldResource
     */
    public WorldResource() {

    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of rest.WorldResource
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public String getXml() {
        //TODO return proper representation object
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/countries")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getCountries() {
        list = db.getAllCountries();
        String jsonEx = gson.toJson(list, List.class);
        return Response.status(200).entity(jsonEx).build();
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of WorldResource
     * @param content representation for the resource
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public void putXml(String content) {
    }
}
```

and my ApplicationConfig is this:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package rest;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

/**
 *
 * @author William Pfaffe
 */
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    /**
     * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
     * It is automatically populated with
     * all resources defined in the project.
     * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
     */
    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(rest.WorldResource.class);
    }

}
```

I have tried almost everything, trying different return types, rather than returning response objects. The result is the same everytime.

**EDIT: THE ISSUE IS COMING FROM MY ENTITYMANAGER!!! 
THE CODE FOR MY DBMAPPER IS DISPLAYED BELOW!

**A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on rest.TestResource**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package DBMapper;

import entity.Country;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author William Pfaffe
 */
public class DBMapper {

    private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu");
    private EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    public List<Country> getAllCountries() {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c from Country c");
        List<Country> list = query.getResultList();
        return list;
    }

    public List<Country> getCountryGreaterThanPopulation(int population) {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c from Country c where c.population > :popu");
        query.setParameter("popu", population);
        List<Country> list = query.getResultList();
        return list;
    }

    public List<Country> getCountryByCountryCode(String cc) {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c from Country c where c.code = :cc");
        query.setParameter("cc", cc);
        List<Country> list = query.getResultList();
        return list;
    }

    public Country getDenmark() {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c from Country c where c.code = :cc");
        query.setParameter("cc", "DNK");
        Country list = (Country) query.getSingleResult();
        return list;
    }

}
```

Comment: did you miss noticing the `Status: 404 Not found` ?

Comment: What is 'the result'? What's do you expect to happen, what actually happens, what is the difference,etc

Comment: check in `raw` tab

Comment: I expect the result to be a JSON array of countries. I have a method from my Database mapper, which fills the List<Countries>.

Comment: The only thing significant in your error screenshot is the 404. Ignore all the rest until you get that fixed.

Comment: Have I written the URL for the get request wrong?

Comment: URL actually looks OK, assuming your application context is indeed worldrest.

Comment: I tried making a request towards the standard link (http://localhost:8084/worldrest), and I get the correct display of my index.html. However when adding my application path and REST path, I still get a 404 message.

Comment: Strange. Are you sure that your REST application is being handled by your application server? Did you include the required libraries/configuration? You should get at least get some output in your application server's log to indicate that the JAX-RS application has been scanned.

Comment: what app server are you deploying to, and what version? do you have a web.xml? could you share that too (if it's not blank)

Comment: I have added all dependencies needed. You might be right that it's not being handled correctly by my server, as it won't read it. I created the REST API by creating a RESTful Service from Pattern in Netbeans.

Comment: what server is it, tomcat, glassfish, something else?

Comment: It's being deployed by Tomcat version 8.0.27.0. My dependencies are described here: http://i.imgur.com/xIFtupl.png

Comment: change the type in the resclient from json to text to see what is is actual result. Currently it's json and the string which you are getting is not valid json.

Comment: does the app deploy clean, and no unexpected errors or messages when it deploys? do you have a web.xml file? can you share the content?

Comment: The issue seems to be coming from my Persistance unit, which is in one of my DBMappers. The root cause is at line 21 in my DBMapper, where the EntityManager is.

Comment: I took a copy of your code and dropped in a web project in Eclipse, deployed to Tomcat 8.0.41, removed everything but returning a pojo class with some values set (I added Jackson to my pom.xml to handling mapping to json), and can confirm that you've got everything setup right. Looks like you're already making progress tracking down the issues, but it's not with the Jax-rs config,you're all set there.